# 'Warning: [react-router] Location "/test" did not match any routes' using react-router with express at server-side router

Tags: html, reactjs, express, react-router, router

I'm using React-router module.
and, React-router is well nice work!

but the problem is that if I set up router in Express router, then it will get error.
ex)

**Server-side JS**

```
import express from 'express';
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
```

And I add to set up router on server-side of express

```
app.get('/test', function(res, req){
    res.send('test works!');
});

app.post('/postTest', function(res, req){
    res.send('post test work!');
});
```

but all of this code have error

```
-> Warning: [react-router] Location "/test" did not match any routes
```

I'm just setting router in server-side but the web has error.
I think express router do not work on server....

how can I use server-side router?

I have Form tag in HTML with method of POST to transport data to database.
So I need to server-side router...

How to use server-side router with react-router module??

Comment: How are you redirecting to /test?

Comment: redirecting? instead of send to redirect? as res.send() -> res.redir ?

Comment: I meant routing

Comment: Well, I was changing code to res.send to res.redirect. And I refresh the page but it still...

Comment: Usually with those 2, you will use react-router for client side navigation and displaying react components, and you will use express routes as an API. If you're interested in server side rendering, you should look at the react-router help page for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks but is it possible ? those 2 things usually use on the web made by react?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: No, Not thing, Just I know my attempt is correct or not way like use react-router and express router. I'm not certain my code...T^T

Comment: Well, I don't know, I can't see your client code

Comment: @paqash anyway, thanks! your kindness. I need more study on react-router . Thank you! :)